# Spring MVC bean data flow

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I got task unfortunately from work to create page using spring mvc, but i never work with that. I have to do that web app with restricted specifications which are following:

JSP cannot contain javascript, java, jstl only spring mvc tag's, but it's not everything. Controller must containt vaiable's only inside methods, all methods can return only String or void, so I'm unable to use @ModelAttribute, ModelMap, Model to move data from one view to another.

Is it possible to create page with following rules? I dont realy know how beans work in Spring MVC, but it seems that it will doesnt work without it.

Comment: You can inject a `Model` as a handler method argument.

Comment: @RequestMapping("/projektowanie/formularz{idFormularza}")
    public String getFormularz(@PathVariable int idFormularza, Model model) {
        Formularz form = new KlientWebservice().pobierzFormularz(idFormularza);
        model.addAttribute("formularz", form);
        return "projektowanie/podglad_formularza";
    }
I already do it, but I'm still unable to access model from other method